# Cambiar class y name a un input dependiendo de un input radio con jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Teniendo un código así:

```html
<input type="radio" id="campo_1">
<input type="text" class="hidden" name="campo_1">

<input type="radio" id="campo_2">
<input type="text" class="hidden" name="campo_2">
```

Yo quiero que, por ejemplo, al tener `:checked` el radio `#campo_1` quitarle la clase hidden al input con name `campo_1` y cambiarle el name a `micampo`

Cual sería la mejor manera?

```js
$('#campo_1').click(function(){
     if ($('#campo_1').is(':checked'){
      //aquí es donde no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo...
     }
});
```

O hay alguna forma mejor?

Comment: Tienes que tener en mente que name es un atributo, entonces lo que tienes que buscar en jquery es cambiar el valor de un atributo "change attribute value jquery" y con eso encontrarás tú mismo la solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
$("#campo_1").change(function(){
if ($("#campo_1").is(':checked')) { 
      $("[name='campo_1'").removeClass('hidden').attr('name', 'micampo')
    }
});
```

Comment: Esto es lo que había probado gracias al comentario de Alberto León pero no funciona...

Comment: @PavloB. Prueba ahora, he editado mi respuesta. No funcionaba porque faltaba cerrar el paréntesis en el if (no me había dado cuenta).

Comment: Para la próxima vez, como recomendación a los 2, divide la pregunta en 2 preguntas. Una sobre la clase y otra sobre el atributo. Así se pueden hacer respuestas directas sobre cada caso en concreto.